# Can you setup Alexa to remind you about calendar events?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

Is it possible to configure an Amazon Echo so that Alexa will tell you about upcoming events (e.g. from Google Calendar) an hour before each of them by waking itself up and reminding you about them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Alexa can now support reminders](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/6/1/15724474/alexa-echo-amazon-reminders-named-timers):

> You can now say “Alexa, remind me to take out the trash at 6PM,” and it will notify you at the proper time. Alexa still lacks context for AM / PM reminders and alarms (unlike Siri and Google Assistant), which is actively annoying, so don’t forget the abbreviation.

Your best option currently is to use Alexa's [integration with Google Calendar](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201810470) to manually check your schedule every day. You can check your calendar with *"What’s on my calendar on [day]?"*. If necessary, you can also specify a time, e.g. *"What's on my calendar today at 3pm?"*.

You can then set a reminder from your daily briefing for particularly important events, but Alexa can't yet notify you about *every* event on your calendar (and I suspect that would be too noisy to be useful for many people).

Comment: well, it's a pitty that it only goes into one direction. https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/7x0gji/google_reminders_alexa_reminders/    . Somebody found a page with feature requests?

Comment: This is available now.  In the Alexa App: More > Settings > Calendar & Email > Add Account.    In Google Calendar you can configure your calendar to have a notification time for example 1 hour.  Alexa will say something like "From your calendar [event] begins in [time]".  Seems like all events from the same calendar will have the same notification time.  you can configure multiple calendars with alexa, but alexa can only add events to one by voice.  (Sorry to answer in a comment, I can't submit an answer because I don't have 10 points)

Comment: @SketchBookGames I removed the protection from the question so you can now post that as an answer. Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 2):

My experience at least with Outlook Calendar events. If I set the event to give me a reminder at a certain time prior to the event, my echo device will give me a voice prompts the time.  For instance, I have an event tomorrow at 6PM.   I set the event in Outlook Calendars to remind me 24 hours prior.  My Echo just reminded me of this event today at 6PM.   In short, this capability is driven by your calendar program.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon just introduced a "Reminders" feature that allows you set dates and voice messages in advance. Not automatic and not tied to the calendar but works well and is actually useful. Reminds me of weekly calls doctors appointments etc.. I like it

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you would need a diary ‘skill’ that pushed reminders to a designated Alexa device for vocalisation.

Having examined the Skill Development Kit, I believe this would be possible to accomplish via a cloud server, however I have not found an existing Skill which can accomplish this.

Comment: Please elaborate how that would be possible. Otherwise this seems more like a guess than an objective answer.